# Proving an equality involving sums and min functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got stuck trying to prove the following equality. Actually I'm not even sure if it holds:

> If $\ \omega_i^P \geq 0, \ \omega_i^B \geq 0 \ \text{for every } i  \in \{1, \dots, N \}, \ \text{and } \  \sum_{i=1}^N \omega_i^P=\sum_{i=1}^N \omega_i^B=1, $
>
> then
>
> $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N |\omega_i^P - \omega_i^B|=1 -\sum_{i=1}^N \min(\omega_i^P, \omega_i ^B).$

This is my attempt at proving it so far-->

$$
\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N |\omega_i^P - \omega_i^B|=1 -\sum_{i=1}^N \min(\omega_i^P, \omega_i ^B) \\
\iff \\
 \sum_{i=1}^N |\omega_i^P - \omega_i^B|=2 \left( 1 -\sum_{i=1}^N \min(\omega_i^P, \omega_i ^B) \right) \\
\iff \\
 \sum_{i=1}^N |\omega_i^P - \omega_i^B|=2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^N \omega_i^P -\sum_{i=1}^N \min(\omega_i^P, \omega_i ^B) \right) \\
\iff \\
 \sum_{i=1}^N |\omega_i^P - \omega_i^B|=2  \sum_{i=1}^N \left ( \omega_i^P -\min(\omega_i^P, \omega_i ^B) \right) \\
\iff \\
 \sum_{i=1}^N |\omega_i^P - \omega_i^B|=2  \sum_{i=1}^N \left ( \omega_i^P +\max(-\omega_i^P, -\omega_i ^B) \right) \\
\iff \\
 \sum_{i=1}^N |\omega_i^P - \omega_i^B|=2  \sum_{i=1}^N \max(\omega_i^P -\omega_i^P, \omega_i^P -\omega_i ^B)  \\
\iff \\
 \sum_{i=1}^N |\omega_i^P - \omega_i^B|=2  \sum_{i=1}^N \max(0, \omega_i^P -\omega_i ^B)  \\
\iff \\
 \sum_{i=1}^N  \left( \max(\omega_i^P - \omega_i^B,0) + \max(-\omega_i^P + \omega_i^B,0) \right )  =2  \sum_{i=1}^N \max(0, \omega_i^P -\omega_i ^B)  \\
\iff \\
 \sum_{i=1}^N \max(-\omega_i^P + \omega_i^B,0)   = \sum_{i=1}^N \max(0, \omega_i^P -\omega_i ^B)  \\
\iff \\
?
$$

And no clue what to do after this point...Also, what could be a simpler approach to proving this equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $x$ and $y$ are real, $|x - y| = x + y - 2 \min(x,y)$

Comment: Great! It's proven in only two lines using the given equality. Thanks.